# Vim windows navigation inside vim inside vim-terminal not working as expected

Tags: vim

Vim windows navigation breaks for me once I perform these steps:

from (bash in my case) terminal open vim (8.1) in terminal mode

```
>vim -c ":term ++curwin"
```

then from the vim-terminal open vim

```
>vim
```

From inside vim, open a new split window

```
:sp
```

try navigating

```
<C-w><C-w>
```

and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Vim as a terminal emulator and Vim again inside of it, I see. Are you trying to create a black hole?

Anyway, if the built-in terminal allowed this it would function as a keyboard trap, effectively making it impossible to move the focus to another (host) Vim window.

It's really a classic case of the host capturing a keystroke and preventing the hosted program to receive it. Pretty much like screen using `<C-a>` as leader and thus preventing you from incrementing the number under the cursor in Vim.

And just like screen that lets you do `<C-a>a` to send an actual `<C-a>` to the hosted program, Vim's built-in terminal lets you do `<C-w>.` to send an actual `<C-w>`.

Therefore, you can do `<C-w>.<C-w>.` to achieve your goal (however misguided it might be).

See `:help terminal-typing`.

Comment: Ah, so that's the issue.
You raise an interesting point though - why is it such a bad thing to want to do?
People use terminal multiplexers all the time, and add plugins to their multiplexers and to their terminals in an an attempt to make it resemble vim.
vim already has vim-terminal as well as panes ("windows"), tabs, buffers, and everything else that we know and love in vim. so why not use it as a terminal multiplexer, run all sorts of commands in it, some of which just happen to sometimes be >vim?

Comment: Well, people are definitely entitled to do what they want with *their* free software on *their* machine, whether it makes sense or not. Once they surrender to the "use X as Y" ethos and start treating tools as toys there is no shortage of fun to have, silly things to try, and support requests to make. Luckily for them, there are boring people out there, who took the time to learn their tools properly and keep using them as they are supposed to.